# by using datarow, insert a string value

Tags: c#

```
DataRow drEmpty = dsResult.Tables[1].NewRow();

dsResult.Tables[1].Rows.InsertAt(drEmpty, 0);

DataRow drBranch = dsResult.Tables[1].Rows[1];

drBranch[1] = "Branch"; <--error

dsResult.Tables[1].Rows.InsertAt(drBranch, 1);
```

my expected output for this few line of code is to add first empty row data into my dropdownlistbox and second row by adding "Branch" into the it but i failed to do so

Error msg given --
Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in ows_ID Column.  Expected type is Int64.

after that i try to change to

```
drBranch[1] = int64.Parse("Branch");
```

and i get another error

second error msg -- Input string was not in a correct format.

i get the answer that i want already, i will post the answer after 7 hours ,thanks all

Comment: "Branch" is not Int64 ... you know it's not a number... not an integer at all.

Comment: specify the datatype for that particular column as string in dsResult.Tables[1]

Comment: Do you want to convert the string "Branch" to integer? It is a very tricky question...

Comment: i want to add string "Branch" value into int column table, is this possible?

Comment: All those functions that convert a string to int only take those strings which have numeric values like "100", "10".

Comment: What are the columns in that DataRow? It seems that you expect a different column at position 1 than is actually there. Note that they count from 0. Maybe access the column by name instead of position, like `drBranch["value"] = "Branch"`.

Comment: Check this link, maybe it will be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/q/9028029/1577396

Answer (score 0):

In you example `drBranch[1]` represents the `ows_ID` column, which only accepts values of type `integer`. That means only numbers without a decimal point are allowed.

You could convert strings that contain numbers like `"55"` to an integer using `Int64.Parse("55")`, but you can't convert strings like `"Branch"` to integer. You're trying to store a string in the `ows_ID` column. Maybe you're trying to access the wrong index?

Comment: oic, then is it possible for me to add string value "Branch" into int column  table?

Comment: @CheemunLow no it is **not** possible, to add a `string` value into an `int` column.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `"Branch"` is not integer.

To cast a value into integer you need an integer value as a string like `"526"`, `"100"`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you think that the [**column ordinal**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.ordinal.aspx) is one-based but it's zero-based, hence `drBranch[1]` is the second column.

In my opinion it's better to use the column's name instead:

```
drBranch.SetField<String>("Branch", newBranch);
```

(i'm using the [`SetField` ex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353039%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)tension method since it's strongly typed and supports nullables)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a DataTable before using DataRow:

```
DataTabel dtResult = dsResult.Tables[1].Clone();

dtResult.Columns[1].DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

DataRow drEmpty = dtResult.NewRow();

dsResult.Tables[1].Rows.InsertAt(drEmpty, 0);

DataRow drBranch = dsResult.Tables[1].Rows[1];

drBranch[1] = "Branch";

dsResult.Tables[1].Rows.InsertAt(drBranch, 1);
```