# What is the best way to read from excel file without losing data? Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, ado.net

What is the best way to read from excel file without losing data?
Excel sheet have column formated HH:MM:SS when read it using ADO the time format changed to date and lose actual value:

Sample from excel:
[image]

After import to grid view:
[image]

Code:

```
        Try
        ' Clear the DataGridView and the connection string TextBox
        Dim Datatable As New DataTable("Sometable")
        ' Fill the DataGridView and connection string TextBox
        Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Super.Excel_GetConnectionString(txtZDCalc_txtPerPath.Text, txtZDCalc_txtPerPath.Tag))
            connection.Open()
            Using adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & cboxZDCalc_Sheet.SelectedItem & "]", connection)
                adapter.Fill(Datatable)
            End Using
        End Using

        Super.ZD_GetEmployees(Datatable)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Display any errors
        MessageBox.Show("[" & ex.[GetType]().Name & "] " & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
```

Why after import time lose the value ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want to display the TimeSpan instead of a date. Excel stores the value of the cell as a datetime and uses formatting to control how it is displayed.

What you want to do is to change the datatype of the column in your DataTable to TimeSpan

Have a look at here to find out how to do this: [How To Change DataType of a DataColumn in a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028029/how-to-change-datatype-of-a-datacolumn-in-a-datatable)