# GridView is not displaying all columns in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataTable that is populated by an MDX query. I want to bind that DataTable to a GridView and show all data that is returned. My GridView is defined like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID = "gvResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

MDX query is called as follows:

```
DataTable mdxResults = new DataTable();
CellSet cellSet;

AdomdCommand command = new AdomdCommand();

strCommand = "SELECT NON EMPTY({[Measures].[Assets Distinct Count], [Measures].[Value]}) " + 
"ON COLUMNS, NONEMPTY({[Organization].[Org Id].[Org Id]*[Location].[Loc Id].[Loc Id]}) " + 
"ON ROWS FROM [database]"

command.Connection = _CurrentConnection;
command.CommandText = strCommand;
cellSet = command.ExecuteCellSet();
AdomdDataAdapter dataAdapter = new AdomdDataAdapter(command);
objDataAdapter.Fill(mdxResults);
```

An example of a DataTable that could be produced from the MDX query:

```
Organization   Location      Assets     Value
Org A          Los Angeles   12         320000
Org B          San Jose      6          21000
```

Assets and Value are aggregated measures from the MDX query.

The DataTable is then bound to the GridView after I rename columns:

```
gvResults.DataSource = mdxResults;
gvResults.DataBind();
```

After I bind the DataTable only a subset of the columns display in the GridView. Specifically, all columns but  the Measure columns from the MDX query will display.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Insert rest of your GridView code, and example of DataTable

Comment: can you show the code where you are calling the query then binding the results of the DataTable to the Gridview..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being that the MDX query would fill the DataTable with type Object for the Measure results which is not supported by AutoGenerateColumns. To correct this I utilized the solution here to change the DataType before binding to the GridView:
[How To Change DataType of a DataColumn in a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028029/how-to-change-datatype-of-a-datacolumn-in-a-datatable)