# Converting datatype of column from string to double

Tags: c#, datatable

I am reading csv file to DataTable with [GenericParsing lib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F). It reads all data as strings and I don't see any way to tell `GenericParserAdapter` to treat read data as double (leaving first two columns which are date and time, all the rest contain only numeric values).

So leaving this part of code, is there an easy way to convert datatype of existing string column to double?

Comment: Kindly use another Datatable (recreate with same column but different datatype) and in foreach loop copy the rows to new Datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Damn, I wasn't able to find this answer earlier. Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9028087/639956)

```
DataTable dtc = dt.Clone();
for ( int i = 2; i < dtc.Columns.Count; ++i )
    dtc.Columns[ i ].DataType = typeof( double );
foreach ( DataRow row in dt.Rows )
    dtc.ImportRow( row );
```