# How to change value in data row with type mismatch?

Tags: c#, datarow

I have a DataTable that I'm exporting to pdf and there are numeric value like status id that I want to change to strings for example:

```
dataRow["statusId"] = 1; //dataRow["statusId"] type is int
```

and I want it to be:

```
dataRow["statusId"] = "Open file";
```

How can I do it without coping the entire data table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can't do it. The best way is to actually clone the dataTable and then copy each row:

```
DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
dtCloned.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(Int32); //in the column you actually need.
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{
    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Source: [How To Change DataType of a DataColumn in a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028029/how-to-change-datatype-of-a-datacolumn-in-a-datatable)

Comment: Better that way yeah :)