# Loading text File into datagrid and long number displayed incorrectly

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datagrid

I'm importing a `.txt` file into a `DataGridView`, which works pretty decently right now.

Unfortunately, the one and only important value isn't displayed correctly.

The value (a German tracking number) is: "00340433914967320068"

Please see attached screenshot (column F2) how it is shown in the datagrid.
All other values works like charm.

Even longer ones like: `"[x,xx] Gewicht<0>N^[0,00] DHL Paket<101>L^"`

[screenshot shows problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSZhu.png)

Code is:

```
private void buttonEasy1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() ==          System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            this.labeltxt1.Text = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;

            // .txt einlesen Anfang

            string[] lines1 = { "[" + labeltxt1.Text + "]", "Format = Delimited(;)", "ColNameHeader = False "};
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\*\schema.ini", lines1);


            string FileName1 = textBox1.Text;

            OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " +
                     Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName1) + ";Extended Properties='text;';");

            conn1.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter
                   ("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(FileName1), conn1);

            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet("Temp");
            adapter1.Fill(ds1);

            conn1.Close();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "Table";

            // .txt einlesen Ende
```

Comment: I think you need to make that column a String datatype. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028029/how-to-change-datatype-of-a-datacolumn-in-a-datatable

Answer (score 0):

Try changing DataGrid column format. For example:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N0";
```

or

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "###################";
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Jalal! Does the job halfway. Now it displays 340433914967320000 but value is 00340433914967320587. Prefix 00 isn't essential, whereas last 3(4) digits are.

Answer (score 0):

Further Information with regard to Steve's comment -

I tried those solutions:

[How To Change DataType of a DataColumn in a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028029/how-to-change-datatype-of-a-datacolumn-in-a-datatable)

```
DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
dtCloned.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(String);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{
dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}
```

and

```
adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
table.Columns[1].DataType = typeof (String);
adapter.Fill(table);
```

Nothing changed - still displaying 3,40433191496732E+17 instead of 00340433914967320587