# How to change column format in DataTable C#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, format, timespan

In my application returns following datatable,

```
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| AccountName | WaitTime | AssistTime | FName | LName | FullName |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| XXX         | 18       | 15         | Mary  | Sil   |          |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| YYY         | 67       | 3          | Jany  | Joh   |          |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| ZZZ         | 50       | 100        | Kate  | Ham   |          |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
```

In above `datatable`, `WaitTime` and `AssistTime` data coming as double value,Now I need to change the format of `WaitTime` and `AssistTime` columns format to `00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)` format. So I just write folowing code(please be noted this part of code).

```
DataTable tableone = ds.Tables[0];

tableone.Select().ToList().ForEach(row =>
{

    string FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["FName"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string LastName = Convert.ToString(row["LName"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    double xxx = Convert.ToDouble(row["WaitTime"]);

    row.SetField("WaitTime",secondsToTime(xxx));
    row.SetField("FullName", string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName));
});

private string secondsToTime(double seconds)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
    string answer = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
        t.Hours,
        t.Minutes,
        t.Seconds);
    return answer;
}
```

But above code gives this error,

> System.ArgumentException: 'Input string was not in a correct
>   format.Couldn't store <00:00:18> in WaitTime Column.  Expected type is
>   Decimal.'
>   FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

I need following DataTable as formated one.

```
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| AccountName | WaitTime | AssistTime | FName | LName | FullName |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| XXX         | 00:00:18 | 00:00:15   | Mary  | Sil   | Mary Sil |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| YYY         | 00:01:07 | 00:00:03   | Jany  | Joh   | Jany Joh |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| ZZZ         | 00:00:50 | 00:01:40   | Kate  | Ham   | Kate Ham |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
```

How can I do this? please help

Comment: What type is time in the database?  Is it a number, or date object?  It looks like your code is expecting an integer [row.SetField("WaitTime",secondsToTime(xxx));].

Comment: @jdweng `WaitTime` and `AssistTime` are in decimal values in database. Can you please tell me what is difference of your code `[row.SetField("WaitTime",secondsToTime(xxx));]` than my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeff mentioned in his answer, You cannot change the DataType after the Datatable is filled with data. What you can do is, take a clone of the Data table, change the column type and load data from the original data table to the cloned table as follows.

```
DataTable dtCloned = tableone.Clone();
dtCloned.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(string); //In your case you need to change WaitTime and AssistTime
dtCloned.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(string);

foreach (DataRow row in tableone.Rows)
{
    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Then you can use your code as,

```
dtCloned.Select().ToList().ForEach(row =>
{
    double xxx = Convert.ToDouble(row["WaitTime"]);
    row.SetField("WaitTime", secondsToTime(xxx));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are successfully changing values from column WaitTime and AssistTime

now just follow the below steps

```
        DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();

        dtTemp = dtOri.Clone();
        dtTemp.Columns["WaitTime"].DataType = typeof(TimeSpan);
        dtTemp.Columns["AssistTime"].DataType = typeof(TimeSpan);
        //you can change data type to string as well if you need
        //if you are changing datatype to string make sure to add ".ToString()" in below code e.g secondsToTime(xx).ToString()

        foreach (DataRow row in dtOri.Rows)
        {
            dtTemp.Rows.Add(new object[] {row[0], secondsToTime(Convert.ToDouble(row[1].ToString())), secondsToTime(Convert.ToDouble(row[2].ToString())), row[3],row[4],row[5]});
        }

        dtOri = dtTemp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of your WaitTime column is a decimal so you cannot set it to a TimeSpan. You cannot change the column types of DataTables after they have been populated so you'll have to change it at the source or create a clone.

See this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9028087/1532710

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can I do that using clone datatable, please help me. and actually I don't need set TimeSpan.  `secondsToTime` function returns string value. can you please provide me a complete answer

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by clone database. A DataTable is a .Net in memory representation of your data. You can either define one manually with a designer, in code, or allow the framework to create one for you automatically from your data source. The other answers have shown one way to customize your data table by cloning it and changing the types. You could also change the column types at the root source (api service or database).