# Unable to change type of DataColumn after Reset

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

DataTable seemes still has data after reset. I do somethig like:

```
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        myTable.Columns.Add("myColumn");
        myTable.Columns["myColumn"].DataType = typeof(double);
        DataRow myRow = myTable.NewRow();
        myTable.Reset();
        myTable.Columns.Add("myColumn");
        myTable.Columns["myColumn"].DataType = typeof(double);
```

and get exception "Cannot change DataType of a column once it has data", though .Reset method was called.

Comment: Refer to this post. Looks like you're unable to change the datatype once the datatable is created. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028029/how-to-change-datatype-of-a-datacolumn-in-a-datatable